# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I encountered this error saying:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fit'`

```
from the following code:
```

```
models = [[GMMHMM(n_components=3,n_mix=2,verbose=False,n_iter=10) for i in range(39)]]

p_bar = tqdm(range(39))
#### ---- Training the models ----

for i in range(39):
    p_bar.set_description('{}. Training "{}" Phoneme Model'.format(i,fc.get39Phon(i)))
    models[i].fit(features[i],lengths[i])
    p_bar.update()
```

How can I solve this?

I tried removing the extra bracket form
`models = [[GMMHMM(n_components=3,n_mix=2,verbose=False,n_iter=10) for i in range(39)]]`

and got this new error:
`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "How can that happen?" This is the wrong mindset. Instead, please clearly explain: why do you think it should not happen? Step by step, what do you expect the code to do? What do you think should be the result of `models[i]`, and why should it be possible to use `.fit` with that result?

Comment: You have an extra pair of brackets. Maybe you want `models = [GMMHMM(n_components=3,n_mix=2,verbose=False,n_iter=10) for i in range(39)]`.

Comment: @ILS I put the extra pair of brackets because of my previous error about arrays saying

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I appreciate your advice. Thank you. I'll do better next time.

Comment: "because of my previous error about arrays saying ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" It is important to understand that Python's built-in `list` type (what you get by using `[]` around a list comprehension or an explicit list) has **nothing to do with** the Numpy (I am **guessing**) `array` type which is (**apparently**) created by the `GMMHMM` library function. Please read [ask] and [mre], and also try to make sure that you **understand the fundamentals** of the tools you are using before trying to ask questions about them. We cannot offer guided tutorials here.

Comment: My **guess** (because you did not show any `import` statements, mention the libraries you are using, etc. etc.) - based on how things are named in your program - is that you are trying to do something to do with neural networks. If you "are very new to Python" then **please study the basics of Python first** and make sure you understand how to [examine](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Python code and understand what is going on (for example, what all the **types** are), before trying to use sophisticated third-party libraries.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, `models` is a list of lists, because you have double brackets. Change the first line to:

```
models = [GMMHMM(n_components=3,n_mix=2,verbose=False,n_iter=10) for i in range(39)]
```

... and this sould work.

P.S.: Please try to use reproducible code when asking quenstions.

Comment: I put the extra pair of brackets because of my previous error about arrays saying:

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that don't meet site standards (i.e. the answer is described as fixing a typo, or the code in the question is not a proper MRE).